# Плавающий  и перетаскиваемый блок + кросбраузерность

Tags: jquery

Здравствуйте,
подскажите плагин или свои наработки следущего:
необходим блок (например меню), который можно перетащить в любое место страницы + который будет всегда на виду при прокрутке страницы.
Желательно, чтобы такое работало во всех популярных браузерах

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jqueryui.com/draggable/ Читаем про событие stop http://www.site-do.ru/js/jquery10.php

Comment: Это только перетаскивание - таких куча в сети...
Нужен такой, чтобы перетащенный в любое место страницы блок никогда не скрывался при скролле

Comment: @fulltext, объясняю для непонимающих. В плагине draggable есть событие stop. То есть после наступления конца перетаскивания можно выполнять свой код. Вот по наступлению этого события давайте совему блоку position: fixed и все. Вуаля, вы восхетительны.

Comment: спасибо за разъяснение, попробую
а для использования этого плагина нужно всю UI подключать, или есть отдельный (легкий) вариант?

Comment: а подключить UI так сложно? один скрипт и один css =))) это вообще то очень легкое решение)

Comment: ага, 400kb+ весит..

Comment: @NoName, просили простой способ - показал простой. тем более сжатая версия весит 220Кб =) Если не нравится такой вариант, то надо писать самому, что, мне кажется, автору не очень подходит =)

Comment: уговорил))